# Web filter URI selection is wrong

Tags: web.xml, servlet-filters

I have a web filter which is defined in web.xml as

```
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>ABCFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am logging few details using this filter. One of the detail is URI of the web page. 
When I go through index.html(or any html page), the URI logged is not of that page, but URI of an image I use on that page.

Eg, if URI is "/index.html"; the URI in log file is "images/banner.gif".

when I specify the url-pattern as "*.html" it is calculating correct uri but with url-pattern as /* ,it logs wrong data.

Any kind of input will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/*` covers all requests. This includes requests for static resources such as CSS/JS/image files referenced by the HTML page. You seem to be not aware that web pages work that way. You seem to somehow expect that all necessary resources are served in the same response as the web page request. This isn't true. HTML doesn't work that way.

You need to modify the URL pattern of your filter in such way that it only matches the URLs of interest. For example, if the common pattern of all those URLs is that they end up in `.jsp`, then just use `*.jsp` as URL pattern.

```
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

Do note that you can specify multiple `<url-pattern>` entries in a single mapping. So the below is also valid:

```
<filter-mapping>
    ...
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If there's however no specific common pattern, e.g. because you use URL rewriting to strip off extensions and there's no common folder, then you should move all static resoruces like CSS/JS/image files into a common folder, e.g. `/resources/`, and then add a check in the filter to exclude that path from the business job.

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

```
String resourceURI = request.getContextPath() + "/resources/";
boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(resourceURI);

if (!resourceRequest) {
    // Log request.
}

chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

It isn't possible to add an "exclude" URL pattern to the mapping.